# How do I specify the type of the next parameter based on the type of the previous parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like

```
type messageType = 'msg' | 'peerCommon'
type peerCommonMessageType = 'hangUp' | 'disconnect' | 'inviteReject' | 'partyReject'
interface reciveMessage {
    type: messageType
    message: string | peerCommonMessageType
}
```

I want the type of message to be string when the Type is msg, and the type of message to be peerCommonMessageType when the Type is peerCommon, how do I modify the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a discriminated union:

```js
type messageType = 'msg' | 'peerCommon'
type peerCommonMessageType = 'hangUp' | 'disconnect' | 'inviteReject' | 'partyReject'

interface msgMessage {
    type: 'msg';
    message: string;
}

interface peerCommonMessage {
    type: 'peerCommon'
    message: peerCommonMessageType
}

type reciveMessage = msgMessage | peerCommonMessage;

// Passes
const test1: reciveMessage = {
    type: 'msg',
    message: 'any string'
}

// Fails
const test2: reciveMessage = {
    type: 'peerCommon',
    message: 'any string'
}

// Passes
const test3: reciveMessage = {
    type: 'peerCommon',
    message: 'hangUp'
}
```